# Get value of array and display it into dropdown as parent and child

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working in codeigniter. I want to display category dropdowna as parent category and its subcategory in sequance. Here I have an array like this:

```
Array
(
[category] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [Name] => web
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2
                [Name] => Travels
                [child_cat] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 3
                                [Name] => Food
                            )

                    )

            )
     )
)
```

Here I want to display **Travels** as **parent category** in dropdown box and display **Food** under the **Travels** category.

I have created select box like this :

```
<select class="form-control" id="sel1">
    <option value="0">Select</option>
        <?php
            foreach($category as $cat)
            {
                 if($cat['child_cat'] == "")
                 {  
        ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $cat['id']; ?>"><?php echo $cat['Name']; ?></option>
        <?php
            }
                 else
                 {
                    foreach($cat['child_cat'] as $ch)
                    {
        ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $ch['id']; ?>">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $ch['Name']; ?></option>
        <?php
                    }
                }
           }
        ?>
</select>
```

Here it can not show **Travels** as parent category. **Food** is show under the web instead of Travels. So what code should I have to write?

Comment: you want the code in php, or displayed in html? because with dropdown i think of html so think of <optgroup>

Comment: @baboizk I want to display it into html.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried to far and take a [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to understand how to ask good questions.

Comment: You can use combination of `foreach` loops with simple `echo`. "So what code should I have to write?" - is a bad question for SO :)

Comment: is this a hack or what ? how can `labana` open a bounty on a question from `nisarg Bhavsar` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like the one below

```
<select id="test">
    <?php foreach($category as $category):?>
        <?php if($category['child_cat']){?>
            <optgroup label="<?php echo $category['name'];?>">
            <?php foreach($category['child_cat'] as $child):?>
                <option value="<?php echo $child['id'];?>"><?php echo $child['name'];?></option>
            <?php endforeach;?>
            </optgroup>
        <?php }else{ ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $category['id'];?>"><?php echo $category['name'];?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php endforeach;?>
</select>
```

Comment: If child has sub-child then what I have to do?

Comment: Its working only first level of child, if i want to work while nth child then??

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested optgroup in your code.

```
<select>
    <optgroup label="Level One">
        <option> A.1 </option>
        <optgroup label="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Level Two">
           <option>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; A.B.1 </option>
        </optgroup>
        <option> A.2 </option>
    </optgroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

View

```
<select id="main_cat" name="main_cat">
    <option value="">Select Category</option>
    <?php foreach($categories as $cat) {
        $selected = ($cat_id == $cat['cat_id'] ? 'selected="selected"' : '');
        echo '<option value="' . $cat['cat_id'] . '" ' . $selected . '>' . $cat['cat_name'] . '</option>';
   } ?>
</select>

<select id="subcategory" name="subcategory">
       <option value="<?=@$childcat_id;?>">
           <?=(!empty($childcat_id) ? $childcat_name : 'Select Category First');?>
      </option>
</select>

<select id="childcategory" name="childcategory">
       <option value="<?=@$subcat_id;?>">
           <?=(!empty($subcat_id) ? $subcat_name : 'Select Category First');?>
      </option>
</select>
```

Script

```
//For Main Categories.
$('#main_cat').on('change',function(event,params){
        $cat_id = params.selected;
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?=site_url("era/subcategory/retrive");?>',
            type: 'GET',
            data: {'catid': $cat_id},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
            {
                var newSubcats = $.map(data, function(subcat){
                    return '<option value="' + subcat.subcat_id + '">' + subcat.subcat_name + '</option>';
                })
                $('#subcategory').html(newSubcats);
                $("#subcategory").trigger("chosen:updated");
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {

            }
        });
    });

//For Sub Categories.
$('#subcategory').on('change',function(event,params){
        $subcat_id = params.selected;
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?=site_url("era/child_cat/retrive");?>',
            type: 'GET',
            data: {'subcat_id': $subcat_id},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
            {
                var newSubcats = $.map(data, function(subcat){
                    return '<option value="' + subcat.subcat_id + '">' + subcat.subcat_name + '</option>';
                })
                $('#childcategory').html(newSubcats);
                $("#childcategory").trigger("chosen:updated");
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {

            }
        });
    });
```